# Firestore DB loading time vs RT DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore with an app that I'm trying to do. I've done a `documentSnapshot.toObject(Something.class)` to pick a value from a specific documents. And then assign it to a TextView.

However, upon opening the app, this TextView takes a few microsecond more to load. Everything else appears first.

Should I instead use Real Time Database for this particular operation?

Comment: It will make no difference. The term "Realtime" might be misleading in this particular case. Either way, they still function as a kind of backend and that small latency is expected.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and comment @Chisko

Comment: You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807159/improve-firestore-offline-cache-android).